# Is Android L device act as a Beacon Now?

Tags: android, ibeacon, estimote

In Android 4.3, i understood as an Android devices can't act as a Beacons because of not supporting for BLE Peripheral mode. But, Android L comes with supporting for BLE Peripheral Mode. So, Is it possible to the Android Devices now act as a Beacons? If yes, Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is now possible.  We have an app available in Google Play and sample code in the Android Beacon Library.

See here for more info:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/18/beacon-transmission-with-android-5.html

Comment: Yes, Its a perfect solution. But we have to wait until Android 5 devices to test. Thanking you **Davidgyoung**

Comment: It's not supported by all Android 5.0 Lollipop Devices. Currently only Nexus 6 and 9 support this feature since it is partially hardware based (Bluetooth 4.1). I have a Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 Lollipop and I'm left out because it only supports Bluetooth 4.0.